# login page that only appears when the user is logged out

Tags: ios

i'm developing an iOS app that needs a login page , i need that login page to only appear when the user is logged out otherwise the app should take them to home page or whatever page that follows the login page 
any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the logout value in `NSUserDefaults` ,while run the application check the value which is placed in `NSUserDefaults` and based on that value redirect o your screen.

in login viewController viewDidLoad method put this code.

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"logout"] isEqualToString:@"No"]){

  //push to your home view controller class
}
```

in login success method keep this one,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"logout"];
```

in logout button click method put this one,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"No" forKey:@"logout"];
```

Comment: i inserted this code under the if statement [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logoutseg" sender:self], it doesn't work in The viewDidLoad , and when i put it in the viewDidAppear , the loginViewController stays for on or two seconds and then navigate to the next page , any help ?